# Error: Zeptojs Animate Is Not A Function

Tags: javascript, zepto

zeptojs document [here](http://zeptojs.com/#animate)
when I use $().animate function throw error like below:

TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function

And the version I used is the page provides.

Comment: Have you [downloaded](http://zeptojs.com/#download) it and included it in your page? Looks like you need to use a selector in [`$()`](http://zeptojs.com/#$()) too

Comment: @Phil: It is downloaded (probably). If it wasn't, then the error would be `$ is not a function` or `$ is not defined`.

Comment: animate is not in main zepto file but a module. So you need to download the fx.js module file at http://zeptojs.com/#modules and import it as a script in your file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(...).animate is in the zepto fx module. It's no longer in the base main distribution of zepto!

http://zeptojs.com/#modules

Comment: Please add it as comment.

Comment: Great answer. Too bad slideUp and slideDown are still EXCLUDED from the zepto library and zepto FX. Should be called 'exzepto' library.